# Make re-usable transition with render functions in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently working on a slide modal. Similar to [Bottom Sheet Vuetify's](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/bottom-sheets/) but instead it should slide from left to right. Besides that I would like to use a re-usable component.

My `SlideLeftTransition.ts`

```
import { defineComponent, createElement as h } from '@vue/composition-api';

export const SlideLeftTransition = defineComponent({
  setup(_, context) {
    return function render() {
      return h('transition', {
        props: {
          name: 'animated slideInLeft',
          mode: 'out-in',
        },
      }, 'default' in context.slots ? context.slots.default() : null);
    };
  },
});
```

Then I'm using the component as follow:

```
import { defineComponent, createElement as h } from '@vue/composition-api';
import { SlideLeftTransition } from '@/ui/components/transitions/SlideLeftTransition';

export const ModalSidePanel = defineComponent<ModalSidePanelProps>({
  setup(props) {
     return function render() {
        return h(SlideLeftTransition, [
          h('div', { style: { display: props.active ? 'block' : 'none' } }, 'this text should appear from left to right sliding'),
        ])
     }
  }
})
```

With my current scss being:

```
$animationDuration: 1;

.animated {
  animation-duration: $animationDuration;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes slideInLeft {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideInLeft {
  animation-name: slideInLeft;
}
```

Unforgettably no slide animation is rendered. The element just magically appears into the screen when being toggled via a button. There's almost no documentation on how to use render function with transitions. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues:

1. `<transition>.name` should only be a single string (not delimited). This string is used as the class name applied *during the animation*. I presume you want the name to be `slideInLeft`.

   ```js
   // SlideTransition.ts
   return h('transition', {
     props: {
       // name: 'animated slideInLeft', ❌
       name: 'slideInLeft', ✅
       mode: 'out-in',
     },
   })
   ```
2. The transition styles file (`SlideTransition.scss`) should be imported in `SlideTransition.ts`, so that the styles are applied to the content elements.

   ```js
   // SlideTransition.ts
   import './SlideTransition.scss'
   ```
3. The transition styles should target `__TRANSITION_NAME__-enter-active` and `__TRANSITION-NAME__-leave-active`:

   ```css
   .slideInLeft {
     &-enter-active {
       animation: slideInLeft .30s;
     }
     &-leave-active {
       animation: slideInLeft .15s reverse;
     }
   }
   ```
4. The default slot of the `<transition>` must be added/removed for the animation to take effect, so `ModalSidePanel`'s render function must *conditionally* provide the child element instead of using `display:block/none`. Also be sure to declare your `props` using the Options API:

   ```js
   export const ModalSidePanel = defineComponent({
     props: {
       active: Boolean
     },
     setup(props) {
       return function render() {
         return h(
           SlideLeftTransition,

           // static child (no transition) ❌
           h('div', { style: { display: props.active ? 'block' : 'none' } }, '...'),

           // conditionally added ✅
           props.active && [ h('div', null, '...') ]
         )
       }
     }
   })
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-transition-component-with-render-function-ek5hn?file=/src/components/ModalSidePanel.js)

Comment: When Im answering questions in Stackoverflow about VueJS I always see you poping out in the question answers. I have huge admiration towards your VueJS knowledge and feeel proud and thankful to have received such a good written answer from you @tony19.